# Sending URL Parameters to a Python REST API using Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, api, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to send URL parameters to an API I wrote on Python, using Javascript. 
My Javascript code is as follows:

```
function createGetRequest() {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', 'some-link/api/', true);
        request.onload = function() {
            var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
            document.getElementById("idk").innerHTML = data.news.entry_news_item_title + "</br>" + data.news.entry_news_item_snippet + "</br>"
            + data.news.entry_news_item_url;
        }
        request.send();
    }
```

and my Python REST API code is as follows;

```
def index():
NewsFeed = feedparser.parse("https://trends.google.com.tr/trends/trendingsearches/daily/rss?geo=TR")

entry = NewsFeed.entries[0]

return {"news" : {"Status" : "OK",
                              "item" : entry['title'],
                              "entry_news_item_title" : entry['ht_news_item_title'],
                              "entry_news_item_snippet" : entry['ht_news_item_snippet'],
                              "entry_news_item_url" : entry['ht_news_item_url']}}
```

I want to be able to get the index of the entry from the user and then return the corresponding entry. In other words, I want the `entry = NewsFeed.entries[0]` part to accept a variable rather than a 0. I have tried everything online yet I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Use something like `request.open('GET', 'some-link/api/?entry=' + entry);` then in your Python API, grab the `entry` param.

Comment: I think that comment is more than enough to be an answer for this question :) why don't you elaborate a little more and make it as an answer? @ChrisG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your JavaScript code add entry to GET request as follows:

```
function createGetRequest() {
    // code to get number/id you are clicking on
    entry_id = getEntryId();
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //After question marks you can input your GET request parameters
    request.open('GET', `some-link/api/?entry=${entry_id}`, true); //I am using backticks as interpolation  
    request.onload = function() {
        var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
        document.getElementById("idk").innerHTML = data.news.entry_news_item_title + "</br>" + data.news.entry_news_item_snippet + "</br>"
            + data.news.entry_news_item_url;
        }
        request.send();
    }
```

In you Python code you need just to collect get parameters from request string as follows:

```
# Add the request parameter to the function
def index(request):
    NewsFeed = feedparser.parse("https://trends.google.com.tr/trends/trendingsearches/daily/rss?geo=TR")
    # Get the parameter from request
    # By using get function if you do not have a parameter with given key it will return None 
    entry_id = request.GET.get('entry')
    if entry_id:
        entry = NewsFeed.entries[entry_id]

        return {"news" : {"Status" : "OK",
                          "item" : entry['title'],
                          "entry_news_item_title" : entry['ht_news_item_title'],
                          "entry_news_item_snippet" : entry['ht_news_item_snippet'],
                          "entry_news_item_url" : entry['ht_news_item_url']}}
    else:
        # Handle bad request
        return {"news":None}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! For some reason, when I app the parameter to the GET request, I get an Internal Server Error. Can this be because I use AWS EC2 as my server? Do I need to specify these parameters through API Gateway maybe? I am spitballing here I kind of do not know what to do.

Comment: Also, how should the @app.route() look with this integration?

Comment: I assume you are using Flask, to use routing with get parameters you do not need to use anything special just as usual:
`@app.route('some-link/api/')`

Comment: When do you get this error?
Also try to encode your url params
`let data = encodeURIComponent('entry') + '=' + encodeURIComponent(entry_id);
request.open('GET', 'some-link/api/?' + data, true)`

Comment: I have not done anything special to integrate Flask so if it is not the default, no I am not using it.

Comment: It seems like I get the error when I put the parameter within the `entry = NewsFeed.entries[0]` part (in the place of the 0). Otherwise, I can pull the parameter and display it fine. When I put the parameter inside the square brackets, I get:

`{"Message":"An internal server error occurred.","Code":"InternalServerError"}`

Comment: Apparently I needed to typecast the variable to an integer.